# How can I add a graticule similar to the DeLorme Atlas to a map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I've got a map in NJ State Plane (Feet) projection and want to add a grid to it with lat and long intervals of 1 minute, and 0.1 minute tick marks. I'm trying to do this in the grid tab in the print composer but getting wonky results (probably some user error here!

[image: Here's a screenshot. Note that my projection is set to NAD83 State Plane NJ (feet)]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your post to include a screenshot or description of what kind of 'wonky results' you are getting, and/or the dialog showing the settings you are using. As it stands we don't have much to go on in terms of what might be wrong since you're in the right place (dialog box).

Comment: done! Note - the wonky results are the 1 degree resolution I get on my grid which are not representative of the actual coordinates of the region.

Answer (score 1):

Your grid CRS (epsg:32111) is in projected coordinates. You'll need to choose a geographic CRS (such as epsg 4326) to get a grid in lat/long.